# " You can only create a user with a password in a contained database." Error while importing bacpac from SQLAZure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a .bacpac file generated from an Azure SQL instance that I am trying to import to a local SQL Server Instance.
I am using the Import Data Tier Application wizard but getting the following error:

```
 TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Could not import package.
Warning SQL72012: The object [Backup_20170609-184846_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72012: The object [Backup_20170609-184846_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 33233, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 You can only create a user with a password in a contained database.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE USER [JOB_ENTRY_MANAGER]
    WITH PASSWORD = N'balh';


 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
```

There aren't any options in the Wizard but it looks like I need to turn something on?

I've read that I need to run the following, but I can only run it against Master (as the destination DB doesn't exist)

```
EXEC sp_configure 'contained', 1; RECONFIGURE;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which has been fixed in Latest releases of SSMS...

IF you are not using latest version of SSMS, prior to that you need to run this script

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Below is the connect item which has more details  :
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1274164/error-when-importing-azure-bacpac-as-contained-database

this [link has few more details on approaches used](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/85bb12e8-5ae4-409c-93fa-8a9d025c6b35/error-when-importing-a-datatiers-application-from-azure-db-as-contained?forum=ssdt) ,if you are not on latest version of SSMS

> When i edit a bacpac from a local Contained DB, i find this property :
>
> But this property is missing in bacpac azure DB export.
>
> After editing model.xml into the bacpac, and generate a new Checksum, the data base import finish successfully !! :)

Comment: This script didn't work for me against the version of SSMS I had for SQL Server 2014. I have updated to SSMS v17.1 and run the script and now it does, hurrah.